# How to get ip range from aws kubernetes cluster and add it to my database cluster whitelist

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-vpc

I have a database cluster that needs to set IP range into the whitelist. I set up a kubernetes cluster and run my app. How can I give/get the kubernetes cluster an IP address so that I can set it to my whitelist?

Thank you~

Comment: Which tool have u used to set up ur `k8s` cluster? `kops`? `kubeadm`?

Answer (score 1):

If you can SSH into the cluster, you can run "ip addr show" to get the ip address.

Answer (score 0):

- Check your `VPC`'s `CIDR`
- Go to the Inbound rules of your database's security group
- Allow all inbound traffic on port `3306` from the above `CIDR`

Hopefully this allow everything in your `kubernetes` cluster to reach your database.

There are of course more fine-grained and complex solution for security policies (e.g. allow **only specific pods** to reach your db) but that is most likely another story / question.